# Проникновение в бд

Tags: sql

Я знаю, что запрос от пользователя на неком сайте проходит таким образом:

`$param = stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($_POST['param']))`

Возможно ли это обойти? :)

Comment: а что он принимает? (тип данных)

Comment: Он может может принимать как и ing так и char

Comment: Это смотря, что дальше с этим самым `$param` происходит. `htmlspecialchars` не защитит от SQL-команд в переменной. Насчёт примера, какие ошибки могут в принципе быть, почитайте http://bobby-tables.com/ru_RU/

Comment: Млин, какой эротичный вопрос!

Answer (score 0):

Местами нужно поменять

```
htmlspecialchars(stripslashes(
```

хотя хз в чем вопрос то
данный экранируются

еще можно в `htmlspecialchars( ,ENT_QUOTES)` дописать второй параметр

тогда будет преобразовывать все подряд, все символы

При добавлении в базу нужно использовать другую функцию

```
mysql_real_escape_string()
```

Comment: Так это у не у меня на сайте :) Я просто знаю, что на сайте так "защищаются". Вопрос, как это возможно обойти?)

Comment: обойти не получится

Comment: ну если в базу таким способом экранируется то тогда обычные sql иньекции подойдут

Comment: Да, таким образом идет проверка в бд. Можете дать свой скайп, буду очень благодарен.

Comment: Я бы сотню раз подумал, прежде чем давать хакеру свои координаты. :-P

Comment: :P Тогда такой вопросик, каким образом реализовать SQL-Иньекцию?) Вот например в чате?) Там такая же обработка)

Comment: У кого есть время научить нуба SQL-Инъекции, прошу добавить меня в скайп komar12124 ^^ заранее спасибо))

Comment: /* До чего скриптикиддисы ленивые пошли */

Купите себе [толковую книжку](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/5238324/) и не страдайте.

Comment: Судя по объему, грехов там гораздо больше :)